# Outdoor Wi-Fi positioning / poor man's GPS on RPI3 Model B

Tags: pi-3, wifi, gps

I got used to Google Maps [figuring where I am using surrounding Wi-Fi signals](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-google-and-everyone-else-gets-wi-fi-location-data/), a.k.a. [Wi-Fi positioning system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system). I try it on my laptop and it works, but on my Raspberry PI it doesn't: using Firefox ESR, it locates me as if I'm in the center of the country's capital.

I [searched here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=wifi%20location), as well as Google and the official forums. Most of the results I'm getting either cover indoor positioning, or rely on using external GPS receivers/hardware.

Is there any way to get it to work using just the internal Wi-Fi module?

Comment: THe article you referenced was a good one, and reveals the cleverness of **Gswine**, but you haven't indicated how or where you get this "WiFi based location". Is it simply "Gswine Maps", or is there a "special feature" that needs selection to get this?

Comment: @Seamus I get the Wi-Fi based location by going to [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com) on my laptop and clicking the target icon at the lower right of my screen. My browser then prompts me whether I agree to share my location, and once approved, it zooms the map right to where I am. Honestly, as a Google Maps user, I'm not even sure what Gswine is.

Comment: And you did this from your RPi also - that is to say click and agree?

Comment: @Seamus yes, sure. I repeated the process step by step and it did resolve, but the location it showed was the center of the capital city, even though my public IP resolves to another city (where I actually am). Same procedure on my laptop resolves the accurate location

Comment: did you get a message suggesting we move this to the chat facility?

Comment: Apparently not - here's the comment: " I think there are 2 possibilities: 1) Firefox ESR is not forwarding your agreement to Gswine, 2) you're using a different ISP on your Pi than on your laptop."

Comment: @Seamus thank you for the suggestions. Can you please clarify what **Gswine** is? I searched Google but [there's nothing](https://www.google.com/search?q=gswine+linux).